# cannot import name 'type_spec_registry' from 'tensorflow.python.framework'

Tags: python, tensorflow, rllib

I am working on my Master's project with MARL, and i decided to use RLLib. I created a conda environment for my project and installed RLLib:

`pip install "ray[rllib]" tensorflow`

Later on, i tried to run one experiment:

`rllib train --algo DQN --env CartPole-v1`

But got the following error: "ImportError: cannot import name 'type_spec_registry' from 'tensorflow.python.framework'"

I am using Tensorflow 2.11.

Thanks in advance!

I was trying to run one experiment from RLLib library in order to test if the library is correctly installed.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue after installing `tf-nightly` then reverting back to `tensorflow` v2.11.0.

I'm unsure of root cause, but downgrading tensorflow to version 2.10.1 fixed it on my machine. After this I was able to upgrade back to 2.11.0 without the import exception.

```bash
# downgrade
pip install tensorflow==2.10.1
# tensorflow was working at this point

# then upgrading to the latest worked as well
pip install -U tensorflow
```